# How to start a service on Alpine Linux?

Tags: init, alpine-linux

I'm trying to start services (Mysql, Grafana...) on an Alpine Linux.

I've tried to do so with `openrc`.

When I do `rc-service mariadb start` I get `Warning: Service is already started`, which I assume means that the service is starting (?)

Yet the process doesn't seem to run:

- if I do a`ps` command, I don't see any mysql process
- if I launch the mysql secure_installation_script, I get the following error message: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`

I get the same sort of result with other services such as Grafana or InfluxDB.

What I'm I doing wrong ?

(Alpine is not installed on my computer: I'm working inside a container based on an Alpine docker image.)

Comment: try restarting the service with  rc-service mariadb restart

Comment: @JoshuaBeckers, thanks but I get the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the "runlevel" by default, the runlevel is set to sysinit... i switched to "default" runlevel and it works